# Fetch data out to xml file stored locally in resources directory of xcode project

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, listview, uitextfield

I want to design a simple app which fetches data out of xml file stored locally in resources when ever user enters a string in text field, all the possible relevant strings should be printed. Can anyone help me with that or give me some example to refer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you will want to [read this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html) for the XML files. There should be a download source code at the top of the screen.

Also check out [this forum](http://p2p.wrox.com/xml/7595-search-replace-text-xml-file.html), they discuss searching for text inside an XML file. Hope this helped.

Comment: thanks but XSLT is not available for iphone and i already went through SeismicXML example, but i am still not able to fetch data locally. If you have any link or example specifically regarding that than please share. Thanks a lot